# remove_before()

Tags: php, string

Is there some better way to do the below?
(without having the possibility of a fatal error)

```
function remove_before($needle,$haystack){
    return substr(strstr($haystack,$needle),strlen($needle)); 
}
```

like strstr($haystack,$needle) but without the needle in the returned string,
and I might as well ask if this can be improved too...

```
function remove_after($needle,$haystack){
    return substr($haystack, 0, strrpos($haystack, $needle));
}
```

note that remove after strips the string after the last occurrence of needle, and remove before strips the string before the first occurrence of needle.

**edit:**
example:

```
$needle = '@@';
$haystack = 'one@@two@@three';
remove_after($needle,$haystack);//returns one@@two
remove_before($needle,$haystack)://returns two@@three
```

**edit:**
I will leave it here for other people to reference.

Comment: any reason you need a better way?

Comment: why don't you use the strstr-function?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel
because I thought php had a built in function for this...
@Codler
because it's not the same?? or is it? I tried it and it gave me a different result.

Comment: not to mention that you can always check function list in the manual yourself, but even if there was such a function - so what? what's bad with your own one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things about the functions as written:

They have no error handling.  For example, in remove_before: needle not in haystack causes it to pass `false` as the first argument to `substr`.  I haven't tried it, but I'm pretty sure this will cause a runtime error.

In `remove_before`, `strpos` is faster and less memory intensive than `strstr`.

Therefore:

```
function remove_before($needle, $haystack){
    $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    // No needle found
    if (false === $pos)
        return $haystack;
    return substr($haystack, $pos + strlen($needle));
}
```

and likewise, `remove_after`:

```
function remove_after($needle, $haystack){
    $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
    // No needle found
    if (false === $pos)
        return $haystack;
    return substr($haystack, 0, $pos);
}
```

Comment: I was sure too that it would return a runtime error, but it didn't. IMO PHP needs to have these functions built in...