# PHP remove everything before last instance of a character

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to remove everything before and including the last instance of a certain character?

I have multiple strings which contain `>`, e.g.

1. `the > cat > sat > on > the > mat`
2. `welcome > home`

I need the strings to be formatted so they become

1. `mat`
2. `home`

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove_before()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403476/remove-before)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use a regular expression...

```
$str = preg_replace('/^.*>\s*/', '', $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kDJamb).

...or use `explode()`...

```
$tokens = explode('>', $str);
$str = trim(end($tokens));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/N0He3y).

...or `substr()`...

```
$str = trim(substr($str, strrpos($str, '>') + 1));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vofYPz).

There are probably many other ways to do it. Keep in mind my examples trim the resulting string. You can always edit my example code if that is not a requirement.

Comment: which is the least and most expensive operation for the suggestions above?

Comment: @Julian Profile and see! I'd suspect the last one may be the fastest.