# cut bunch of words from text file

Tags: grep, cut

i am trying to get a last part from 800 lines and saving it into a new file using bash :

**example**

```
framework/resources/Functional/tpcds/variants/json/q3_1.sql
metastore/scripts/upgrade/derby/hive-schema-1.3.0.derby.sql
coeus-db/coeus-db-sql/src/main/resources/co/kuali/coeus/data/migration/sql/mysql/rice_server/bootstrap/V400_002__KR_RICE_01_1.0.3.2-2.0.0_2010-04-15_B000.sql
sql/Updates/0.0.3/r1358_mangos.sql
coeus-db/coeus-db-sql/src/main/resources/co/kuali/coeus/data/migration/sql/mysql/kc/bootstrap/V521_047__KC_DML_01_KRACOEUS-7036_B000.sql
src/FrontEnd/db/1.x/1.1/src/02.functions-and-logic/office/office.get_office_name_by_id.sql
```

**I want the output to be like**

```
q3_1.sql
hive-schema-1.3.0.derby.sql
V521_047__KC_DML_01_KRACOEUS-7036_B000.sql
V400_002__KR_RICE_01_1.0.3.2-2.0.0_2010-04-15_B000.sql
V521_047__KC_DML_01_KRACOEUS-7036_B000.sql
office.get_office_name_by_id.sql
```

Can someone please tell me how do i achieve it using cut/grep command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP remove everything before last instance of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382547/php-remove-everything-before-last-instance-of-a-character)

Comment: I did not saw that question was not PHP related. .. Still maybe gives an idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the following AWK command instead: `awk 'BEGIN{FS = "/"} {print $NF}'`